# How to display a text in a QTextEdit by clicking on a button?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to display a text in a QTextEdit after I clicked on a button.

I have:

```
QGroupBox *groupDefClass = new QGroupBox("Definition of the class");
QFormLayout *formDefClass = new QFormLayout;
QLineEdit *name = new QLineEdit;
QLineEdit *motherClass = new QLineEdit;

formDefClass->addRow("&Name:", name);
formDefClass->addRow("Mother Class :", motherClass);
groupDefClass->setLayout(formDefClass);

QVBoxLayout *vertBoxAll = new QVBoxLayout;
vertBoxAll->addWidget(groupDefClass);
```

Then I have another textBox somewhere else:

```
textResult = new QTextEdit();
vertBoxAll->addWidget(textResult);
```

And I wanted to add the "code" using this button:

```
generButton = new QPushButton("Generate...");
connect(generButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(getData(code)));
```

And the getData:

```
void SetUpPage::getData(QString code) {
    textResult->setPlainText(code);
    textResult->setReadOnly(true);
    textResult->setFont(QFont("Courier"));
    textResult->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);
}
```

But nothing happens.

I also tried to add textResult->setPlainText(code) directly in the SLOT (not sure if I can do that) but still nothing.

I really don't see what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

1) This `SLOT(getData(code))` contains error - replace `code` with QString.

2) Launch under debugger and catch this error at runtime. Call `qInstallMessageHandler` and show message boxes to force similar errors be shown without debugger.

3) Use function-pointer signal/slot `connect` to prevent this kind of errors in future.